# Restricting access to AWS S3 Bucket Objects only when requests are made from certain domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy

I have created a bucket policy to try and stop hotlinking to my S3 files from people who gain the direct URL. I only want my website to be able to access those files. However when I direct link even with the below policy, it still allows access to the file. The files are all set to public.

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1491040992219",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt14910401236760",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "https://mywebsite.com/*"
                }
            },
            "Principal": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt14910403436760",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": "http://localhost:8888/*"
                }
            },
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do I need to change any settings on the actual S3 bucket settings to stop all access?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the **Deny** statement. Try this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1491040992219",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt14910401236760",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://mywebsite.com/*",
                        "http://localhost:8888/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt14910401236761",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "https://mywebsite.com/*",
                        "http://localhost:8888/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I suspect the objects have `x-amz-acl: public-read` on them, and depending on the overall desired result, the fix should be applied to the objects by removing that.